# operation on groups of rows in a matrix/data frame

Tags: r, matrix, split, dataframe

Let's say I have a matrix (could be a data frame coercible to matrix, or vice verse)

```
X=matrix(rnorm(45), nr=15 )
          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
 [1,] -0.35659671 -0.5014418 -0.90051481
 [2,] -2.84945987 -0.6558198 -1.59163998
 [3,] -0.03612257  0.7118217 -0.76520379
 [4,]  2.45922337 -1.4965018 -0.28132609
 [5,] -0.46939481 -2.2576689 -0.91045703
 [6,]  0.65121124 -0.4879071 -1.81893484
 [7,] -0.28633954  0.3570085 -2.40230043
 [8,] -1.32283279 -0.4904968  0.42214466
 [9,]  0.55199355 -1.5181311 -0.62465292
[10,] -1.00114458  0.5140162 -0.01261708
[11,] -1.49307374  0.1734213  1.38231439
[12,] -1.71157588 -0.7030724 -1.05475532
[13,]  1.13823870  1.3380262  2.74988880
[14,] -0.41600520 -0.9527629  0.68447386
[15,] -1.25893418 -0.3633260  0.38870010
```

Getting the column sum is easy (*colSums*, or *apply*, or whatever preferred method). However, I have a position index, let's say

```
idx=c(3,7,13)
```

So I need to split the matrix and sum up (or, in general, perform some function) on columns in the subsections, like for rows 1 to 3, 4 to 7, 8 to 13, and 14 to 15 (last row) and get 4 by 3 matrix

```
          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -3.2421792 -0.4454399 -3.2573586
[2,]  2.3547000 -3.8850690 -5.4130180
[3,] -3.8383947 -0.6862365  2.8623225
[4,] -1.6749390 -1.3160890  1.0731740
```

This is a minimal reproducible example. The real matrix is much larger, number of subsections and their positions are variable, and the function is more complex :)

Comment: an approach with `Map` provides a good oneliner but @akrun first solution is fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 indx <- c(idx[1],diff(c(idx, nrow(X))))
 rownames(X) <- rep(seq_along(indx), indx)
 res <- rowsum(X, group=rownames(X))
 dimnames(res) <- NULL
 res
 #         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
 #[1,] -3.242179 -0.4454399 -3.257359
 #[2,]  2.354700 -3.8850693 -5.413018
 #[3,] -3.838395 -0.6862366  2.862323
 #[4,] -1.674939 -1.3160889  1.073174
```

Or if we convert the 'matrix' to 'data.table` after changing the row.names,

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 as.data.table(X, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=rn]
 #  rn        V1         V2        V3
 #1:  1 -3.242179 -0.4454399 -3.257359
 #2:  2  2.354700 -3.8850693 -5.413018
 #3:  3 -3.838395 -0.6862366  2.862323
 #4:  4 -1.674939 -1.3160889  1.073174
```

Or using `dplyr` before changing the rownames in 'X'

```
 library(dplyr)
 as.data.frame(X) %>% 
            group_by(rn=rep(seq_along(indx), indx)) %>%
            summarise_each(funs(sum))
 #rn        V1         V2        V3
 #1  1 -3.242179 -0.4454399 -3.257359
 #2  2  2.354700 -3.8850693 -5.413018
 #3  3 -3.838395 -0.6862366  2.862323
 #4  4 -1.674939 -1.3160889  1.073174
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `Map` and then `do.call` with `rbind` to get the wanted matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(u,v) colSums(X[u:v,]), c(1, idx+1), c(idx, nrow(X))))
```